# Why is this dynamic allocation leaking memory?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, heap-memory

I have a dynamically expanding bloom filter implementation in c on windows. The size of expansion for each round is expected to be ~4MB but it results on the allocation of 37.7MB on each expansion case. Here are the codes:

**Declaration:**

```
unsigned char **bloom_filter;
const int EXPAND_SIZE=1;
const int COLUMNS=4397164;//~4MB
int bloom_filter_rows=1;
```

**Allocation**

```
bloom_filter=malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(unsigned char*));
for(int i=0;i<bloom_filter_rows;i++)
    bloom_filter[i]=malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(unsigned char));//initially bloom_filter is just COLUMNS size
```

**Expansion**

```
int old_size=bloom_filter_rows;
int new_size=old_size+1;
char **temp_bf;
temp_bf=malloc(old_size*COLUMNS*sizeof(unsigned char*));
for(int i=0;i<old_size;i++)
    temp_bf[i]=malloc(bloom_filter_rows*COLUMNS*size0f(unsigned char));
//content is copied to temp_bf using iteration here
```

**//free_old_bf()**

```
for(int j=0;j<old_size;j++)
    free(bloom_filter[j];
free(bloom_filter);
```

**//expand**

```
bloom_filter=malloc(new_size*COLUMNS*sizeof(unsigned char*));
for(int i=0;i<new_size;i++)
    bloom_filter[i]=malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(unsigned char));
//copy back old content here
```

**//free temp_bf**

```
for(int j=0;j<old_size;j++)
    free(temp_bf[j];
free(temp_bf);
```

Comment: In the expansion, this `temp_bf[i]=malloc(COLUMNS*size0f(unsigned char*));` should be `temp_bf[i]=malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(unsigned char));`.

Comment: The initial allocation should be `bloom_filter = malloc(bloom_filter_rows*sizeof(unsigned char*));`.

Comment: @H.S. the 'temp_bf[i]=malloc(COLUMNS**sizeof(unsigned char*)) '  was typing mistake(it is edited now).

Comment: @SteveSummit bloom_filter_rows is initialized to 1, so I think this  will not have any effect on the size of the allocated memory, except to increase the readability of the code.

Comment: You are allocating a *square* (COLUMNS \* COLUMNS \* something) array. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @wildplasser no, that is not my intention

Comment: @wildplasser It is sort of     `ROWS*COLUMNS*unsigned char `     array on the heap.

Comment: @George I realize that `bloom_filter_rows` is 1.  I understand you want to allocate one row, that is, one `char *` pointer for `bloom_filter` to point to.  But in the code you posted, you're not allocating one pointer, you're allocating 4,397,164 of them.  So that's part of (not all of, but part of) your memory leak.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks a lots. That fixed my problem. Can you tell me what other parts of the code are sources for leaking?

Comment: @George I didn't review all of the code, so I'm not sure.  I assumed there were other problems because (a) the one I pointed out accounts for 4MB of wastage, but you reported ~34MB, and (b) H.S.'s first comment about `sizeof(unsigned char*)` versus `sizeof(unsigned char)`.  But if it's working now -- if the memory usage is as expected -- perhaps you've fixed them all.